# Simple Outlook Encryption, suitable for Office365

Tags: encryption, outlook, office365

I'm looking for a simple Outlook Encryption solution to allow person-to-person encryption.

My requirements:

- Simple to use (will be used by non-technical upper management)
- Supports Outlook 2007
- Supports Windows XP
- Can work with Office365
- Preferably, can use a per-message shared key (password shared between sender and recipient)
- Preferably, has an app for Android

One example I have evaluated is [**Virtru**](https://www.virtru.com/). It integrates well with Outlook 2010 I'm using, and it also integrates with Firefox and Chrome, enabling decryption of email on Office365.

Unfortunately, it requires at least Windows Vista and Outlook 2010.

Do you have a recommendation?

(If you need more information, feel free to ask in the comment)